Getting OOM with G1GC when Xms flag is not given while executing a java program on different java versions
I have written a sample java program to show the behaviour
  1 public class HelloWorld {
  2         public static void main(String [] args) {
  3                 byte[] a = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE-100];
  4                 byte[] b = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE-100];
  5                 System.out.println(a.length);
  6                 System.out.println(b.length);
  7         }
  8 }

Behaviour with JDK 17:

java -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseG1GC HelloWorld.java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:4)


java -Xms2500m -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseG1GC HelloWorld.java

2147483547
2147483547


java -Xms2000m -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseG1GC HelloWorld.java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:4)

4.java -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseZGC HelloWorld.java
2147483547
2147483547

From the above examples when G1GC is used i am getting an OOM exception when i use -Xmx4500m, but the moment i use -Xms2500m -Xmx4500m i am no longer getting the OOM exception.
I tested and found the same behaviour in Java 8 and Java 11 as well. This particular issue is not happening with any other GC algorithm.
Any help is appreciated to figure out the behaviour differences.
java -version
java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)

java -XshowSettings:category
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 17.0.10+11-LTS-240
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 17
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 17.0.10
    java.version.date = 2024-01-16
    java.vm.compressedOopsMode = Zero based
    java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 17
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 17.0.10+11-LTS-240
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = \n
    native.encoding = UTF-8
    os.arch = aarch64
    os.name = Mac OS X
    os.version = 14.4.1

GC logs for Example 1: java -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseG1GC HelloWorld.java
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.602+0530][0.016s][info][gc] Using G1
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.016s][info][gc,init] Version: 17.0.10+11-LTS-240 (release)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.016s][info][gc,init] CPUs: 10 total, 10 available
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.016s][info][gc,init] Memory: 32768M
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.016s][info][gc,init] Large Page Support: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.016s][info][gc,init] NUMA Support: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Compressed Oops: Enabled (Zero based)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Heap Region Size: 4M
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Heap Min Capacity: 8M
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Heap Initial Capacity: 512M
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Heap Max Capacity: 4504M
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Pre-touch: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Parallel Workers: 9
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Workers: 2
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Refinement Workers: 9
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.603+0530][0.017s][info][gc,init] Periodic GC: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.631+0530][0.044s][info][gc,metaspace] CDS archive(s) mapped at: [0x0000007000000000-0x0000007000be0000-0x0000007000be0000), size 12451840, SharedBaseAddress: 0x0000007000000000, ArchiveRelocationMode: 1.
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.631+0530][0.044s][info][gc,metaspace] Compressed class space mapped at: 0x0000007001000000-0x0000007041000000, reserved size: 1073741824
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.631+0530][0.044s][info][gc,metaspace] Narrow klass base: 0x0000007000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0, Narrow klass range: 0x100000000
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.894+0530][0.307s][info][gc,start    ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.894+0530][0.307s][info][gc,task     ] GC(0) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Evacuate Collection Set: 1.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Other: 0.4ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Eden regions: 4->0(7)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0->1(1)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Humongous regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(0) Metaspace: 8959K(9216K)->8959K(9216K) NonClass: 7878K(8000K)->7878K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc          ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 17M->6M(520M) 1.886ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(0) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc          ] GC(1) Concurrent Undo Cycle
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.895+0530][0.309s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.898+0530][0.311s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 2.325ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:16.898+0530][0.311s][info][gc          ] GC(1) Concurrent Undo Cycle 2.368ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.075+0530][0.489s][info][gc,start    ] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.075+0530][0.489s][info][gc,task     ] GC(2) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.8ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Other: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Eden regions: 0->0(30)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Survivor regions: 1->1(1)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(2) Metaspace: 8961K(9216K)->8961K(9216K) NonClass: 7880K(8000K)->7880K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc          ] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 2054M->2054M(2552M) 1.229ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(2) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.076+0530][0.490s][info][gc          ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.077+0530][0.490s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.077+0530][0.490s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.006ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.077+0530][0.490s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 0.995ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,start    ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,task     ] GC(4) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.078+0530][0.491s][info][gc,task     ] GC(3) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 1.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.8ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Other: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Eden regions: 0->0(30)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Survivor regions: 1->1(4)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(4) Metaspace: 8961K(9216K)->8961K(9216K) NonClass: 7880K(8000K)->7880K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc          ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 2054M->2054M(2552M) 1.160ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.079+0530][0.492s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(4) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.080+0530][0.494s][info][gc,ergo     ] Attempting full compaction
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.080+0530][0.494s][info][gc,task     ] GC(5) Using 9 workers of 9 for full compaction
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.080+0530][0.494s][info][gc,start    ] GC(5) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.086+0530][0.500s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.088+0530][0.501s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 1: Mark live objects 1.284ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.088+0530][0.501s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.089+0530][0.503s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 1.591ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.089+0530][0.503s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.090+0530][0.503s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.803ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.090+0530][0.503s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 4: Compact heap
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.091+0530][0.504s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.776ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Eden regions: 0->0(56)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Survivor regions: 1->0(4)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Old regions: 0->1
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(5) Metaspace: 8961K(9216K)->8961K(9216K) NonClass: 7880K(8000K)->7880K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.099+0530][0.513s][info][gc             ] GC(5) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause) 2054M->2053M(4504M) 19.050ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.100+0530][0.514s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(5) User=0.02s Sys=0.07s Real=0.02s
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.100+0530][0.514s][info][gc,ergo        ] Attempting maximum full compaction clearing soft references
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.100+0530][0.514s][info][gc,task        ] GC(6) Using 9 workers of 9 for full compaction
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.100+0530][0.514s][info][gc,start       ] GC(6) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.100+0530][0.514s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.102+0530][0.516s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 1: Mark live objects 2.065ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.102+0530][0.516s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.103+0530][0.516s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 0.559ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.103+0530][0.516s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.104+0530][0.517s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.793ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.104+0530][0.517s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 4: Compact heap
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.104+0530][0.518s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.738ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Eden regions: 0->0(56)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Survivor regions: 0->0(4)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Old regions: 1->1
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(6) Metaspace: 8961K(9216K)->8955K(9216K) NonClass: 7880K(8000K)->7876K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1079K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.106+0530][0.520s][info][gc             ] GC(6) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause) 2053M->2053M(4504M) 5.977ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.107+0530][0.520s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(6) User=0.02s Sys=0.01s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.107+0530][0.520s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark From Roots 29.275ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.107+0530][0.520s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Abort
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.107+0530][0.520s][info][gc             ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle 30.326ms
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.108+0530][0.521s][info][gc,heap,exit   ] Heap
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.108+0530][0.521s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  garbage-first heap   total 4612096K, used 2106860K [0x00000006e6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.108+0530][0.521s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   region size 4096K, 1 young (4096K), 0 survivors (0K)
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.108+0530][0.521s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  Metaspace       used 8962K, committed 9216K, reserved 1114112K
[2024-04-16T13:45:17.108+0530][0.521s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   class space    used 1080K, committed 1216K, reserved 1048576K

GC logs of example 2: java -Xms2500m -Xmx4500m -XX:+UseG1GC HelloWorld.java
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.078+0530][0.010s][info][gc] Using G1
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Version: 17.0.10+11-LTS-240 (release)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] CPUs: 10 total, 10 available
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Memory: 32768M
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Large Page Support: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] NUMA Support: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Compressed Oops: Enabled (Zero based)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Heap Region Size: 4M
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Heap Min Capacity: 2504M
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Heap Initial Capacity: 2504M
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Heap Max Capacity: 4504M
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Pre-touch: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Parallel Workers: 9
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Workers: 2
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Concurrent Refinement Workers: 9
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.081+0530][0.013s][info][gc,init] Periodic GC: Disabled
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.085+0530][0.017s][info][gc,metaspace] CDS archive(s) mapped at: [0x000000e800000000-0x000000e800be0000-0x000000e800be0000), size 12451840, SharedBaseAddress: 0x000000e800000000, ArchiveRelocationMode: 1.
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.085+0530][0.017s][info][gc,metaspace] Compressed class space mapped at: 0x000000e801000000-0x000000e841000000, reserved size: 1073741824
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.085+0530][0.017s][info][gc,metaspace] Narrow klass base: 0x000000e800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0, Narrow klass range: 0x100000000
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.310+0530][0.242s][info][gc,start    ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.311+0530][0.243s][info][gc,task     ] GC(0) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.9ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.2ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(0)   Other: 0.4ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Eden regions: 4->0(30)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0->1(4)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(0) Humongous regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(0) Metaspace: 8963K(9216K)->8963K(9216K) NonClass: 7883K(8000K)->7883K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc          ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 19M->6M(2512M) 1.752ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(0) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc          ] GC(1) Concurrent Undo Cycle
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.312+0530][0.244s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.320+0530][0.252s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 7.744ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.320+0530][0.252s][info][gc          ] GC(1) Concurrent Undo Cycle 7.801ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.539+0530][0.471s][info][gc,start    ] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.541+0530][0.473s][info][gc,task     ] GC(2) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.542+0530][0.474s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.542+0530][0.474s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.7ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(2)   Other: 2.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Eden regions: 0->0(30)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Survivor regions: 1->1(4)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(2) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(2) Metaspace: 8965K(9216K)->8965K(9216K) NonClass: 7885K(8000K)->7885K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc          ] GC(2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 2054M->2054M(2512M) 3.823ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(2) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc          ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.006ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.543+0530][0.475s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 0.839ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,start    ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,marking  ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,task     ] GC(4) Using 9 workers of 9 for evacuation
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.544+0530][0.476s][info][gc,task     ] GC(3) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.9ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Merge Heap Roots: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Evacuate Collection Set: 0.8ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,phases   ] GC(4)   Other: 0.0ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Eden regions: 0->0(30)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Survivor regions: 1->1(4)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Old regions: 0->0
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,heap     ] GC(4) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,metaspace] GC(4) Metaspace: 8965K(9216K)->8965K(9216K) NonClass: 7885K(8000K)->7885K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc          ] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 2054M->2054M(2512M) 1.085ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.545+0530][0.477s][info][gc,cpu      ] GC(4) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.546+0530][0.478s][info][gc,ergo     ] Attempting full compaction
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.546+0530][0.478s][info][gc,task     ] GC(5) Using 9 workers of 9 for full compaction
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.546+0530][0.478s][info][gc,start    ] GC(5) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.552+0530][0.484s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.553+0530][0.485s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 1: Mark live objects 1.493ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.553+0530][0.485s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.555+0530][0.487s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 2.223ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.555+0530][0.487s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.556+0530][0.488s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.809ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.556+0530][0.488s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(5) Phase 4: Compact heap
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.557+0530][0.489s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.707ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Eden regions: 0->0(56)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Survivor regions: 1->0(4)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Old regions: 0->1
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Archive regions: 2->2
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Humongous regions: 512->512
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(5) Metaspace: 8965K(9216K)->8965K(9216K) NonClass: 7885K(8000K)->7885K(8000K) Class: 1080K(1216K)->1080K(1216K)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.563+0530][0.495s][info][gc             ] GC(5) Pause Full (G1 Compaction Pause) 2054M->2053M(4504M) 16.965ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.564+0530][0.496s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(5) User=0.01s Sys=0.06s Real=0.02s
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.564+0530][0.496s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark From Roots 20.386ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.564+0530][0.496s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Abort
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.564+0530][0.496s][info][gc             ] GC(3) Concurrent Mark Cycle 21.278ms
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.791+0530][0.723s][info][gc,heap,exit   ] Heap
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.791+0530][0.723s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  garbage-first heap   total 4612096K, used 4204435K [0x00000006e6800000, 0x0000000800000000)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.791+0530][0.723s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   region size 4096K, 1 young (4096K), 0 survivors (0K)
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.791+0530][0.723s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  Metaspace       used 8967K, committed 9216K, reserved 1114112K
[2024-04-16T13:48:46.791+0530][0.723s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   class space    used 1080K, committed 1216K, reserved 1048576K


See the explanations of the options at Overview of Java Options.
